# Material with discontinous conductivity

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

Is there a material whose thermal conductivity can be modeled by the function

$$k(T) = \begin{cases}k_1, & T<T_0 \\ k_2, & T\geq T_0\end{cases}$$

where $k_1$, $k_2$ are constants. I believe water would behave like this, considering the conductivity of ice and liquid water. But then I would ask: when modeling the steady state heat equation, since there is a phase change, would one need to add a special boundary condition at the interface?

**Follow up question:**
Is there a material that behaves like that without changing phase?

Comment: Sounds like the [Stefan problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_problem).

Comment: @Chemomechanics I'm thinking of the steady state equation.

Comment: One way to avoid the interface being "special" is to reformulate the problem using enthalpy instead of temperature. Of course the mesh needs to be fine enough so that the results are not unrealistically "smeared out" where the phase change occurs.

Comment: If you are trying to model a realistic situation with water and ice, don't forget that water transports heat by convection, as well as by conduction!

Comment: @alephzero Right. Well, about the first question... is there a material that changes conductivity but not phase?

Comment: If I recall well He when becomes a superfluid has an abrupt change of thermal conductivity, I also would expect superconductors behave similarly.

Comment: Its not like the thermal conductivity of, well, much of anything is actually constant.

Comment: @JonCuster Should have posted this in https://engineering.stackexchange.com lol

Answer (score 2):

It would not be a steady state situation because the boundary would be moving.  Even so, although the temperature at the interface would be continuous, the temperature gradient at the interface would not be continuous.  This is because there would be a jump change in heat flux across the interface, equal to the heat of fusion times the interface velocity times density:  $$\left[-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right]^--\left[-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right]^+=\rho v \lambda$$ This equation says that the heat flux into the interface minus the heat flux out of the interface would be equal to the rate of heat supply required to do the melting.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Is there a material that changes conductivity abruptly with temperature, without changing phase?

Comment: I don't know of any.  But, of course, you can have two different materials joined together at a given location.

Comment: Of course. But then conductivity would not be a function of temperature.

Comment: Good point.  Then I can't really think of a material that would behave like this.  Sorry.

Comment: Note that temperature would likely not be continuous at the interface, although the discontinuity might be very small to measure.